# FieldError at /post/new/ on executing url: <http://localhost:8000/post/new/>

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django 3.0.8
in Python version 3.8.2

I'm getting an FieldError at /post/new/
Exception Type: FieldError
Exception Value: Unknown field(s) (content) specified for Post

PostCreateView is a class-based view in my views.py of under the blog app of my current project

My blog/views.py is here:-

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Post
from django.views.generic import (
    ListView,
    DetailView,
    CreateView,   
)

# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    context = {
        'posts': Post.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/home.htm', context)

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/about.htm', {'title': 'About'})

    # return HttpResponse('<h1> Blog - About page that we want you to see </h1>')

 
def order(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/order.htm')

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.htm'   # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']



class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
   

class PostCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content']
```

---

My blog/urls.py is here:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import (
   PostListView,
   PostDetailView,
   PostCreateView
)

urlpatterns = [
 
   path('about/', views.about, name='blog-about'),
   path('order/', views.order, name='blog-order'),
   path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='blog-home' ), 
   path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail' ),
   path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create' ),

]
```

---

My blog/templates/blog/post_form.html is here:-

```
{% extends "blog/base.htm" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="context-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}     <!-- for security perpose  -->
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="boder-bottom mb-4">Blog Post</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Post</button>
                
            </div>
        </form>
            
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

What wrong is with the code, Please help!!!
I am new to Django and I am completely lost-in here?

I will be very much thankful for your suggestions!!

Thanks and Wellcome

Comment: It looks like your `Post` model has no `content` field...

Comment: I appritiate your feedback but sir if I saw my PostCreateView class, there we have field for content
class PostCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content']

Comment: but that is not the *model* that is the *view*. The `fields` over there specify what fields are used in the form to *create* a `Post` object. So if you mention `'content'` in the `fields`, it means the `Post` object should contain such model field.

Comment: First of all  I am very much thankful to you,

Comment: exactly the reason specified above, because you mention `'content'` in the `fields`, but your model `Post` has no `content` field.

Comment: thank you soo much Mr. Willem Van Onsem, finally, after spending whole day on it I got it now.
it's only because of you,  
I thank you once again

Comment: Please post your `forms.py`